# MongoDB aggregate - lookup if the only minimum number of documents matches

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I Have a collection called "cv" and another collection called "sections"

In the collection "section" I have a field called "ownerCV" which refers to the CV ID

I want to get the CVs which have a minimum of 4 sections

I use

```
([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: UserSection.tableName,
      localField: '_id',
      foreignField: 'ownerCV',
      as: 'sections'
    }
  }, {
    $project: {
      sectionsCount: {
        $size: '$sections'
      }
    }
  }, {
      $match: {
        'sectionsCount': {
          '$gte': 4
        }
      }
    }
  ])
  .skip(count * page)
  .limit(count)
  .toArray();
```

But it takes a big time.

So is there another way i can do that in a fast time?